# Спорные тревоги на закрытых вопросах

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, тревоги

При просмотре списка своих тревог по фильтру "*спорные*", можно увидеть, что тот или иной вопрос закрыт. Таким образом, получается, что тревога была-таки полезной. Почему нет механизма (*автоматического*) изменения статуса тревог для таких случаев? Да, понимаю, что прикладная ценность - невысока, но тем не менее. Любопытно.

Comment: Однозначно поддерживаю! Почти все мои отклонённые тревоги - это либо закрытые, либо удалённые вопросы! Безобразие!

Comment: @PashaPash, вчера я оставил мою первую тревогу на мете с причиной «спам». Вопрос удалили, а мою тревогу отклонили. Почему?